# Adding all the words from a .txt file to an ArrayList of Custom objects

Tags: java, arrays

I have a .txt file in which every line has a single word.  I've created a class called `Word` with a string variable and ArrayList variable.  My objective is to loop through the entire .txt file and store every word in there as an `Word` object.  For example, if the word is "philly", then an object of the class Word would be created with the String `philly` and a Character ArrayList would be created as `[p,h,i,l,l,y]`

The code below will work to store every word in the .txt file in a String ArrayList but my objective with this project has since changed and I now need a way to store it as objects with both variables, not just the string.  The line that I specifically need to replace is `objectArray.fillWord(strLine);`.  It is currently giving me the error message `The method fillWord (String) is undefined for the type ArrayList <Word>`.  How do I alter this to add a specific Word object to the objectArray of Word objects? How can I create an instance for every single word in the txt file within this loop that gives each Word the same name as it has in the txt file? Any help is truly appreciated!

```
import java.awt.List;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class WordRecommender {

public static void main(String[] args) {

   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   String strLine = "";
   ArrayList<Word> objectArray = new ArrayList<Word>();
   try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("engDictionary.txt"));
         while (strLine != null)
          {
           strLine = br.readLine();
           sb.append(strLine);
           sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
           strLine = br.readLine();
           if (strLine==null)
              break;
           objectArray.fillWord(strLine);
       }
        br.close();
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
       System.err.println("File not found");
   } catch (IOException e) {
       System.err.println("Unable to read the file.");
   }
}
```

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Word {

    String wordName;
    ArrayList<Character> uniqueLetters;

    public Word(String wordName, ArrayList<Character> uniqueLetters) {
        this.wordName = wordName;
        this.uniqueLetters = uniqueLetters;
    }

    public Word fillWord(String string) {

        ArrayList<Character> tempArray = new ArrayList<Character>();

        for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) { 
                        tempArray.add(string.charAt(i));
                    }

        Word w = new Word(string, tempArray);

        return w;
    }

}
```

Comment: That's because you're trying to call 'fillWord' on an arraylist of words, and not a word. The collection 'arraylist' does not have the fillWord function. From your implementation it appears you want to call fillWord without an instance, this means the method should be static. More details can be found here: https://www.javatpoint.com/static-keyword-in-java

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Arch2K.  Is there a way that I could use the fillWord method to create an instance.  Ideally the loop would create an instance for every word in the txt file

Comment: Yes, if you make it a static method that returns a word, you would probably want something like "objectArray.add(Word.fillWord(strLine));"

Comment: Alternatively, you could simply change fillWord into a new constructor that just takes in a string. That would allow you to write "objectArray.add(new Word(strLine))". I'll just detail this in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Word {

    String wordName;
    ArrayList<Character> uniqueLetters;

    public Word(String wordName, ArrayList<Character> uniqueLetters) {
        this.wordName = wordName;
        this.uniqueLetters = uniqueLetters;
    }

    public Word(String string) {
        ArrayList<Character> tempArray = new ArrayList<Character>();

        for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) { 
                        tempArray.add(string.charAt(i));
                    }

        this.wordName = string;
        this.uniqueLetters = tempArray;
    }

}
```

This would turn fillWord into a constructor allowing you to change the problematic line to

```
objectArray.add(new Word(strLine));
```

Unrelated side note: I noticed you named the arraylist unique letters. Would you need to filter repeated letters?

Comment: Thank you so much for this!  I do need to filter down to unique letters but I have a method further along in my code that will do that already.

Comment: I just noticed that my code skips every other line in the txt file  Can you identify in the code where this may be happening?  Thanks again for all of your help!

Comment: strLine = br.readLine();
           sb.append(strLine);
           sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
           strLine = br.readLine();

In the above part, you read from the buffer for two lines, but only process one of them, so the other line is merely added to the stringbuilder and not processed.